# Как распределить неопределенную категорию в фиче пропорционально долям известных категорий?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм `df`. Есть фича `feat` имеющая три категории `cat1`, `cat2`, и немногочисленная `Unknown`.

Я хочу избавиться от `Unknown`, раскидав ее по `cat1` и `cat2` так, чтобы она разлетелась по ним пропорционально их доле в датасете. То есть, если изначально было 45% `cat1`, 40% `cat2` и 5% `Unknown`, то нужно, чтобы `Unknown` разлетелась в между `cat1` и `сat2` в соотношении 9/8.

В документации и блогах ничего подобного не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [67]: %paste
df = pd.DataFrame({'feat':np.random.choice(['cat1','cat2','Unknown'],
                                           size=100,
                                           p=[0.45,0.40,0.15])})
## -- End pasted text --

In [68]: df.feat.value_counts()
Out[68]:
cat1       49
cat2       36
Unknown    15
Name: feat, dtype: int64
```

Сначала найдем соотношение между `cat1` и `cat2`:

```
In [69]: pct = df.feat.value_counts() / len(df)

In [70]: ratio = pct.loc[['cat1','cat2']].min() / pct.loc[['cat1','cat2']].max()

In [71]: pct
Out[71]:
cat1       0.49
cat2       0.36
Unknown    0.15
Name: feat, dtype: float64

In [72]: ratio
Out[72]: 0.7346938775510204
```

теперь заменим строки с `Unknown` с таким же соотношением:

```
In [74]: df.loc[df['feat']=='Unknown', 'feat'] = \
    ...:     np.random.choice([pct[['cat1','cat2']].idxmax(), pct[['cat1','cat2']].idxmin()],
    ...:                      size=df['feat'].eq('Unknown').sum(),
    ...:                      p=[ratio, 1-ratio])
    ...:
    ...:

In [75]: df.feat.value_counts()
Out[75]:
cat1    62
cat2    38
Name: feat, dtype: int64
```

проверка соотношения после замены значений:

```
In [76]: pct.loc[['cat1','cat2']].min() / pct.loc[['cat1','cat2']].max()
Out[76]: 0.7346938775510204
```

Comment: Как всегда выручаете)